# Linux APT: обновление ядра из отдельного репозитория

Tags: linux, update, linux-mint, apt

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обновлять ядро из отдельного репозитория?

Ситуация следующая - есть компьютер под Linux Mint, который контролирует технологические процессы, и некоторые программы на нем живут в режиме реального времени. Технические нюансы этого не являются принципиальными в контексте моего вопроса.

Важно другое - на компьютере установлено ядро с RTAI. И его нельзя случайно, в процессе обновления, заменить новой версией обычного ядра.
В то же время остальные компоненты операционной системы и установленные пакеты могут и должны обновляться в обычном режиме службами, отвечающими за это.

Теперь мой вопрос: какие настройки нужно сделать, чтобы как графический менеджер обновлений, так и apt с их компонентами нормально обновляли систему, а ядро - только из отдельного, специально определенного репозитория и ни откуда больше?

Comment: Переведите сообщений на русский язык.

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что они могут? Вы приготовились к тому, что после успешного обновления что-то сломается?

Comment: Простой способ — поставить на холл, а обновлять руками: скачал, запустил `dpkg —install ...`. Второй, не очень надёжный, обеспечить версию ядра в стороннем репозитории всегда новее, чем в дистрибутивном.

Answer (score 0):

> Предположим, что у Вас есть репозиторий, в котором есть Ваша персональная версия Postfix. И Вы хотите, чтобы APT предпочитал Вашу версию поверх официальной.
>   Вы можете установить предпочтения при помощи Origin

```
Package: *
Pin: origin www.rktmb.org
Pin-Priority: 610

Package: *
Pin: origin ftp.fr.debian.org
Pin-Priority: 600`\
```

Просвещаться [здесь](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/AptPreferences). Понятное дело, что вместо звёздочки вы можете подставить свою маску имени пакета.

Чем выше число Pin тем выше приоритет. Плюс, если у вас rt ядро, оно у вас не заменится на обычное, как минимум потому, что у них разные имена пакетов. У рилтаймового в имени пакета будет присутствовать rt.

Comment: Кстати да, правильно собранные пакеты ядра можно ставить совместно.